# Tridiagonal matrix class in Boost c++

Tags: c++, boost

Does boost provide any classes to implement a tridiagonal matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/banded.htm

Answer (score 0):

Besides this, you are probably looking for a matrix where the 3 diagonal are contiguous.
This is provided by a row-major banded matrix, since diagonals are mapped to rows and in row_major these are contiguous.
The 3 diagonals are provided with one allocation and proper pointers can be easily obtained by &m(0,0), &m(1,0), &m(0,1)